# Group Array Into Alphabetical

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I need to render  my array into a group like this:

```
[group]{A}
   abc
   alpha
   apple
[/group]
```

However, it doesn't want to work yet with this code:

```
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
$batch = '';
$previous = strtoupper(substr($array[0], 0, 1));
foreach($array as $value) {
    $firstLetter = strtoupper(substr($value, 0, 1));

    if($previous !== $firstLetter){ 
        echo "[group]{" . substr($firstLetter, 0,1) . "}\n" . $batch . "[/group]\n\n";
        $batch = NULL;
    }
    else{
        $batch.= $value."\n";
    }

    $previous = $firstLetter;

}
```

**Example input:**

```
a
a
a
b
b
c
```

**Example Output:**

```
[submenu] (B)
a
a
a
[/group]

[submenu] (C)
b
[/group]
```

**Output after advice from 'ElefantPhace' in the comments:**

```
[submenu] (A)
a
a
a
[end]

[submenu] (A)
[group]

[submenu] (A)
[group]
```

**Keeping the '$previous = $firstLetter;' after the 'else' gives me:**

```
[submenu] (A)
a
a
a
[end]

[submenu] (B)
b
[group]
```

Which is fine except for the fact that I miss the last item 'c'

NOTE: I left the `$previous` in my group.

Comment: What does your output look like when you run your array through your code.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: I updated my post with an example input/output

Comment: In your else you need to be setting previous to the current first letter. That's why your getting B for a and C for b. And then use previous letter in your group, not first letter

Comment: I updates my code, still not the desired output! I will update my code so you can observe it..

Comment: Answered, and tested my solution - if you want to test yourself, just copy + paste mine and insert this before the code: $array = ['foo','fizz','bar','baz','apples'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way is to avoid the checking if you're using a new letter (the `if($previous !== $firstLetter)` stuff), and instead use the first letter as an index in a new array, like so:

```
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
$treeArray = array();
foreach($array as $el) {
  $firstLetter = strtoupper(substr($el, 0, 1));
  if(!(isset($treeArray[$firstLetter])) ) { $treeArray[$firstLetter] = array(); }
  array_push($treeArray[$firstLetter], $el);
}
```

Now,  you'll have an array which uses each of the first letters as an index, so you can loop through it later to display like:

```
foreach($treeArray as $letter => $contents) {
  echo '[submenu] ' . $letter, PHP_EOL;
  foreach($contents as $el) {
    echo $el, PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working off your code you can make the following changes to get what you want:

```
$array = array("a", "ac", "ab", "bc", "be", "bd", "ce", "cg", "cf");

sort($array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
$batch = '';
$output = '';
$previous = strtoupper(substr($array[0], 0, 1));
foreach($array as $value) {
    //Get the first letter
    $firstLetter = strtoupper(substr($value, 0, 1));
    //Check if in a new group, otherwise add $value to current group
    if($previous != $firstLetter) {
        //In a new group, so prep for the next group.
        $output .= "[group]{" . $previous . "}\n" . $batch . "[/group]\n\n";
        $previous = $firstLetter;
        $batch = '';
    } else {
        $batch .= $value."\n";
    }

}
//Get the last batch.
$output .= "[group]{" . $previous . "}\n" . $batch . "[/group]\n\n";

print($output);
```

This will produce:

```
[group]{A}
a
ab
ac
[/group]

[group]{B}
bd
be
[/group]

[group]{C}
cf
cg
[/group]
```

Hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

A working example using your method:

```
$array = ['alpha','abc','android','braces','barbs','brackets','crabs','cool'];
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
$batch = '';
$previous = strtoupper(substr($array[0], 0, 1));
$count = count($array);
$i=0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    $i++;
    $firstLetter = strtoupper(substr($value, 0, 1));
    if($previous !== $firstLetter || $i == $count){ 
        if($i == $count) $batch.=$value."\n"; 
        echo "[group]{".$previous."}\n" . $batch . "[/group]\n\n";
        $batch = $value."\n";
    }else{
        $batch.= $value."\n";
    }
    $previous = $firstLetter;
}
```

Output:

> [group]{A} abc alpha android [/group]
>
> [group]{B} barbs braces brackets [/group]
>
> [group]{C} cool crabs[/group]

Not very pretty, but it works!